# Functions - confusion regarding properties, as per example in wiki

Tags: functions

Am reading at [wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Abstract_Algebra/Functions), which states 4 examples to state the 3 properties of a function or their composition(s).
 I am confused over the 4th function $f_4$ which is stated to be surjective.
As per my knowledge, a surjective function is one that maps all the co-domain elements. So, a map over the positive reals given by $x \to x^2$ would be not covering all the elements of the co-domain. Or may be I am wrong, and the given function is not a surjective function over integers (positive or otherwise), and is surjective over the positive reals as all values can be taken in the continuum.

If my last statement is correct, then why $f_3$ is not surjective. Please give some example, if feel is needed.

Comment: Why did you mention integers?

Comment: @Atbey In integers, as per my rudimentary knowledge, if $25$ is in co-domain, then the adjacent points are $16$ and $36$. So, all points of the co-domain are not mapped over integers (positive, or otherwise).

Comment: Functions that you mentioned, $f_3$ and $f_4$ on wiki, are defined on real numbers($\mathbb{R}$), not on integers($\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: @Atbey I changed the domain to show my idea of surjective (or onto ) function. It was easy and very familiar to me, than to think about inverse of a real function. I hope I am correct in that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f_4: \mathbb{R}_{\ge0} \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$ with $f_4(x) = x^2$ is surjective because unless $x$ is negative, $\sqrt{x}$ is a positive real number so it covers all the positive real numbers (when we say $f_4(\sqrt{x}) = x$ with the same domain and codomain, it might be easier to see why it is surjective).

$f_3$ is not surjective because notice that codomain is $\mathbb{R}$ and there is no real solution of the equation $f_3(x) = -1$ for example (it has complex solution $i$).

Comment: So, the 'easy' way out is to find if for a given element of the co-domain there would be any element in the domain. I start by looking that which element in the co-domain 'can-not' be mapped. It also means that this 'reverse' approach (though confusing) leads to computation of the inverse function. So, the inverse function is the key to find the surjectivity  property holds or not.

Comment: Please comment on my 'inverse functions'' remark too. I am waiting for your response on that.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Because if you find *just one* element in the codomain that is not mapped, you can directly conclude that function is not surjective. Whether inverse of the function exists or not is something about *bijectivity*. A function is invertible if and only if it is a bijection. So you also have to consider *injectivity* and you can find out whether function is injection or not by similar approach. For example if $f: A \to B$ is not injective, then there exists $a_1, a_2 \in A$ such that $f(a_1) = f(a_2)$ with $a_1 \ne a_2$. If you find just one pair with this property, you are done.

Comment: Since a bijection is both a surjection and an injection, if the function is invertible, then you can conclude that it is a surjection. I don't think the inverse function is the *key* to find surjectivity because surjectivity alone doesn't imply that the function is invertible. Therefore without function being an injection, if you assume that inverse of the function exists, that would be a wrong approach.

Comment: So, it is an exhaustive search for failure cases, if done algorithmically. And need to apply some heuristics too for limiting the search space for failures. Also, 'inverse function' is a separate issue and only when the test for inverse fails can have check for the injectivity, or surjectivity.

Comment: If you think that function is not surjective, then yes, you need to find a failure case that breaks surjectivity to prove your argument. But if you think that function is surjective, without using any specific case, you should prove it in general. Usually, it is harder to prove surjectivity than to disprove it.

Comment: By proving in general, need a proof as given in the page of wiki (stated in the OP) under the 'Properties' section. but, I have a confusion, as that would assume a composition that leads back to an inverse function such that the composition is an identity. But, if injectivity property is not satisfied, then how can we be sure of taking the inverse function's composition. I am sorry, if not able to understand the crux, but all I could gather was that only.

Comment: I got your point. But the function $g$ mentioned there isn't need to be $f^{-1}$. I will give a short example for you to understand:

Suppose $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and $B = \{a,b\}$ and define a surjective (but not injective) function $f:A \to B$ with $f(1)=f(2)=a$ and $f(3) = b$. Then it says you can find a function $g: B \to A$ such that $f \circ g = id_B$. For example take $g(a) = 1$ and $g(b) = 3$. Then $f(g(a)) = f(1) = a$ and $f(g(b)) = f(3) = b$ so $f\circ g = id_B$. But $f^{-1}$ doesn't exist because $f^{-1}(a)$ has more than one values so $f^{-1}$ is not a function at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for removing the roadblock by the example.

Comment: You're welcome, I am glad if it helped you :)

Comment: I have a question regarding composition of functions and their properties, and how to ascertain the properties before-hand. It may not be a logical one, but given the wealth of such examples in abstract algebra, wanted to cover the ground thoroughly. The question is at: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2603306/composition-of-functions-properties. Please help if it is a logical one, and has something to find out.