# Composition of functions - properties

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

It is well known that for same type of functions, the composition also exhibits the same behavior (i.e., injective, surjective, bijective). Also, there is one property that links the functions' properties in the real analysis domain too: If a function $f$ is bijective, then it is monotonic iff $f^{-1}$ is monotonic.

I have a very simple example, as I am not aware of any way (in literature, or wiki or MSE) to find more about properties of compositions thereof. 

 If there are two functions such that one is bijective, and the other is injective, then what can be stated about the composition before-hand (i.e., without trying out the actual composition)

1. First example is $f(x) = x^2, g(x) = x+1$ over the domain of positive reals and co-domain of reals. Here, $g(x)$ is bijective, and $f(x)$ is injective. Also, the both compositions are injective only, as: $f(g(x)) = (x+1)^2, g(f(x)) = x^2 + 1$.
2. Second is of $f(x) = 2x, g(x) = x+1$ over the domain of integers. Here, $g(x)$ is bijective, and $f(x)$ is injective. Also, the two compositions are having same properties as the original one being the last in the composition , as: $f(g(x)) = 2(x+1), g(f(x)) = 2x + 1$. Here, $f(g(x))$ is only injective, while $g(f(x))$ is bijective.

So, what is the reason for the difference of compositions' properties in both examples.

Comment: If we define $f: \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$, $f \circ g$ doesn't exist (I mean it is not a function). The function $g$ need to have the same domain as the codomain of $f$ in order to take composition. And same situation for $g \circ f$ as well. And in your second example, why do you think that $g(f(x)) = 2x+1$ is bijective? If $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, doesn't it cover only the odd integers ($...,-5,-3,-1,1,3,5,...$) in the codomain? So it is an injection but not a surjection.

Comment: @ArsenBerk Thanks for that. I will be more careful.

Comment: I will think about an example as you intended to give, if I find one, I will try to explain the difference on it.

Comment: @ArsenBerk I will be eagerly awaiting for that.

Comment: Interesting you're saying that $x\mapsto 2x+1$ is bijective as mapping $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z$. It is not. Its range is just the set of *odd* integers.

Comment: @user8734617 Really sorry for that, had a different view of the mapping at that time. I thought of as the set of integers being an infinite set, and the range's each element being mapped by domain uniquely. Should have taken a real example to substantiate it.

Comment: @ArsenBerk I might be wrong, but guess that you wanted to refer to something like at page #35, Theorem 0.9, Defn. 0.14 of the Abstract Algebra book by Charles Lanski. It is available on Google books, and if face difficulty can give the complete address of the webpage.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was saying about the compositions.